# Windows File history over internet (or another solution)

Tags: backup

So I have a backup of my HD on a NAS-server in Denmark, but I am in Canada for 7 months.
I have lots of new photos and video, and would like to back them up.

It seems I cannot chose a drive outside the network for Windows File History.
Any suggestions on how I backup my data?

Comment: External USB drive?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Backup solution needed: Hard Drive to NAS via Internet?](http://superuser.com/questions/76419/backup-solution-needed-hard-drive-to-nas-via-internet)

Answer (score 0):

Set up a [VPN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network) to connect to the network the NAS is on.  While the VPN is connected, your computer will think it is connected locally.

Depending on your network and hardware, this can be a simple process.